# Laravel collapsing items in collection with different dimensions

Tags: php, laravel

I have these items in a collection :

```
[
  0 => array:1 [
    2 => array:3 [
      "name" => "Alex"
      "id" => "1"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    8 => array:3 [
      "name" => "Anne"
      "id" => "2"
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "name" => "Joe"
    "id" => "3"
  ]
  3 => array:3 [
    "name" => "David"
    "id" => "4"
  ]
]
```

As you can see the first two items nested with another array, So i did a collapse in the collection:

```php
collect($items)->collapse();
```

result:

```
array:5 [
    2 => array:3 [
      "name" => "Alex"
      "id" => "1"
    ]
    8 => array:3 [
      "name" => "Anne"
      "id" => "2"
    ]
    "name" => "Joe"
    "id" => "3"
  ]
}
```

It removed the items in the collection because there are duplication keys, So how can i keep them and only collapse the first two items ?

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a basic method here, but it works:

```php
<?php

$a = [
    0 => [
      2 => [
        "name" => "Alex",
        "id" => "1",
      ],
    ],
    1 => [
      8 => [
        "name" => "Anne",
        "id" => "2",
      ],
    ],
    2 => [
      "name" => "Joe",
      "id" => "3",
    ],
    3 => [
      "name" => "David",
      "id" => "4",
    ],
];

function resolveThis($b, $a) {
    foreach($a as $value) {
        if(!isset($value['name'])) {
            $b += resolveThis($b, $value);
            continue;
        }

        $b[] = $value;
    }

    return $b;
}

$b = [];
print_r(resolveThis($b, $a));
```

In output I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Alex
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Anne
            [id] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Joe
            [id] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => David
            [id] => 4
        )

)
```

Which I think is what you wanted :)

Comment: thank you but these are too much work and not laravel way. I found the quicker way

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by checking the index type :

```php
collect($items)->map(fn($a) => is_int(key($a)) ? array_merge(...$a) : $a)->filter();
```